# Python Socket async send and receive design

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a python socket client which

1. Send out `message one` (e.g. Hello) every 5 seconds and `message two` (e.g. 15 seconds) every 15 seconds
2. Receive message at any time

I mean to do the send and receive in different thread. However it is still blocking. 
Does anyone has suggestion?

Thread #1

```
threading.Thread(target=Thread2, args=(sock)).start()
sock.recv(1024)
```

Thread #2

```
def Thread2(sock):
    count = 0
    while True:
        sleep(5)
        count = count + 5
        sock.send('Hello')
        if count % 15 == 0
            sock.send('15 seconds')
```

Comment: If you want an answer, please post the relevant part of the code that you have written. Or you'll risk to get the question closed

Comment: @Winston Not enough code. How do you create these threads?

Comment: I added the socket code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not blocking. It's just that your main thread does nothing after first `sock.recv(1024)`. You have to tell it to constantly gather the data:

**MAIN THREAD**

```
threading.Thread(target=Thread2, args=(sock,)).start()
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print data
```

Note that you won't be able to interrupt that process easily. In order to do that you need to set thread as daemon:

**MAIN THREAD**

```
t = threading.Thread(target=Thread2, args=(sock,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print data
```

Also when you are passing `args` remember to pass a tuple, i.e. `args=(sock,)` instead of `args=(sock)`. For Python `args=(sock)` is equivalent to `args=sock`. This is probably the culprit!

I can't see more issues in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just know that the python offers a module called asyncore/asynchat. Can I use that to achieve non-blocking I/O?

Comment: @Winston Sorry for this late response (somehow I've missed the question). Yep, you can use it for non-blocking I/O (I've been using asyncore a bit in my work).

Comment: Is this implementation thread-safe?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan what do you mean exactly? Socket operations are thread safe, a typical OS will guarantee that. Although writing in parallel may lead to interleaved result, while reading in parallel may lead to partial results.

Comment: I mean in case we call `send` and `recv` is invoked at the same time (sending and receiving data at the same time), will it be a problem?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan no, it won't be. As long as there are only two threads, one only reading and one only writing there will be no issue.

Comment: I see, thank you. Also nice to see people addressing comments on their answers after so many years. I wish you good luck in life. :)